# Apache FTPClient retrieve corrupted file from Ubuntu

Tags: java, apache, ubuntu, pdf, ftp-client

I have a problem that I do not see any sense at all with it... I am developing a Java application with Windows but then I deploy it on Ubuntu. It gets a pdf file from an FTP server and keeps it. When I do it with Windows the pdf file is perfect, but when is deployed on Ubuntu, the file is not download correctly. It is a pdf, I can open it and it has some parts of the document that seems to be the same, but more than the 80% of it is too dark or almost white. It happens with all the documents. This is my code:

```
FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();

try {

    ftpClient.connect(ftpUrl, ftpPort);
    boolean login = ftpClient.login(ftpUser, ftpPsw);

    ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
    ftpClient.setFileTransferMode(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
    ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

    if (login) {

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("pdffile.pdf");

        if (ftpClient.retrieveFile("pdffile.pdf", fos)) {
            System.out.println("File downloaded");
        }
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();            
} finally {
    try {
        if (fos != null) {
            fos.close();

        } if (ftpClient != null) {
            ftpClient.logout();
            ftpClient.disconnect();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thank you very much :)

Comment: While it is unlikely that your Ubuntu box has bad memory, it is possible.  Try testing it with memtest86 or memtest86+.  If you do have bad ram, one symptom is commonly document corruption.

Comment: Hi @MichaelCrawford. First of all, thanks for the response! I tested already and everything seems to be OK with the memory...